# Split multiple similar lines into two separate files with Bash

Tags: linux, bash, split

I have a huge file containing multiple subnets, like this:

```
234.245.34.324/24
234.214.23.34/24
234.344.234.14/24
234.214.234.314/24
234.245.34.324/23
234.214.23.34/22
234.344.234.14/22
234.214.234.314/23
234.245.34.324/24
234.214.23.34/20
234.344.234.14/21
234.214.234.314/20
```

They are all with different IP addresses and same subnets, for instance I have 2340 subnets with `/24`.

Now, I want these split into 2 files, where 50% of all the `/24` splits are in each file, same for `/23`, `/22` `/21` etc.

I know that I can split with `split -l` but that will only give me the line. The purpose is to get an equal number of subnets into both files.

This should be done in Linux bash, since it will be automated.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: sorry, forgot to say that this should be done in linux bash, since it will be automated

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Personally, I'd start by filtering into into a file (presumably in a temporary directory) per mask size -- ie. a file named `20` with all the `/20`s, a file named `19` with all the `/19`s, etc; that's trivial to do with GNU awk; then you just take half of each file.

Comment: hi, i have tried this so far which splits the lines into another file, but it still keeps them in the main file. cat newsub.csv |sort -tr| awk '0 == NR % 2'

Comment: @kryd, does that honor your intent of filtering by mask length?

Comment: @kyrd, by the way, don't use `cat` like that. `sort -tr <newsub.csv` is much more efficient than `cat newsub.csv | sort -tr` (not just because it avoids the overhead of piping through `cat`, but because it lets `sort` seek around in the file instead of needing to buffer everything itself if it needs random access). If you want to write it left-to-write for aesthetic reasons, you can do that: `<newsub.csv sort -tr`.

Comment: ...also, DavidPostill gives you good advice. I'm actually being somewhat badly behaved here by spoonfeeding you an answer without asking you to improve your question first; keeping the questions high-quality is part of keeping the site in good condition as much as keeping the answers high-quality is.

Comment: hi both, you are probobly right, i just got the advice from a friend to ask here for the specific question and maybe didnt read through the guide as i should. thanks for your answers anyway, will try what you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have bash 4.3 available, an implementation that avoids using temporary files might look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#      ^- important: use bash, not sh, as shell

# sort into an array per mask length
declare -A masklens=( )
while IFS=/ read -r addr masklen; do
  [[ $addr ]] || continue
  masklens[$masklen]=1
  declare -a "addrs_${masklen}"
  declare -n addrs="addrs_${masklen}"
  addrs+=( "$addr" )
done

exec 3>"$1" 4>"$2" # open output files
for masklen in "${!masklens[@]}"; do
  declare -n addrs="addrs_${masklen}"
  fmt="%s/${masklen}\n"
  printf "$fmt" "${addrs[@]:0:(${#addrs[@]} + 1) / 2}" >&3
  if (( ${#addrs[@]} > 1 )); then
    printf "$fmt" "${addrs[@]:(${#addrs[@]} + 1) / 2}" >&4
  fi
done
exec 3>&- 4>&- # close output files
```

...invoked as...

```
$ splitfiles out1 out2 <infile
```

Comment: in fact i didn't had bash 3.4, so i recieved a few errors from declare but it seems to be doing what it should. i had to remove duplicate lines also with uniq -u but it seems to have done the magic, thanks

Comment: This certainly won't work right without `declare -n`; your output will be wrong (it would be building one big array, instead of an array per mask length and splitting them individually).

Comment: ...also, you might be getting duplicate output (copied for each masklen seen) if running this on a bash without `declare -n`.